# Google ad on iOS does not fit within constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c

My GADBannerView is setup with a constraint of 50 height and 320 width and is centered horizontally. When the view loads it starts an adreqeust for my iOS emulator like so:

```
NSLog(@"Google Mobile Ads SDK version: %@", [GADRequest sdkVersion]);
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];

self.googleBanner.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx";
self.googleBanner.rootViewController = self;
[self.googleBanner loadRequest:request];
```

The ad loads just fine but in order to see it I have to scroll it into position.

Here is a screenshot of my workspace and constraints:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the emulator and how I have to scroll the adbanner

> [image]

edit:

I found a solution to my problem here [[AdMob GADBannerView loads advertisement outside of view's visible area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371250/admob-gadbannerview-loads-advertisement-outside-of-views-visible-area])

The trick was to uncheck "Extended Edges ... Under Top Bars" in the nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem here [[AdMob GADBannerView loads advertisement outside of view's visible area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371250/admob-gadbannerview-loads-advertisement-outside-of-views-visible-area])

The trick was to uncheck "Extended Edges ... Under Top Bars" in the nib.